# Screen manager cycling through instead switching to the correct screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

My screen manager keep cycling through all the screens inside it instead of switching to correct screen when i clicked on the button.

I have no idea what went wrong and why it turns out like this

main.py:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main"))

        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv:

```
ScreenManager:
    MainScreen:


<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    navigation_rail: navigation_rail
    sm_cfg: sm_cfg
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "Settings"            
            elevation: 10
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            MDNavigationRail:
                id: navigation_rail
                type: "unselected"
                current_selected_item: 0
                MDNavigationRailItem:
                    icon: "account-details-outline"
                    on_active: sm_cfg.current = "screen_my_account"
                MDNavigationRailItem:
                    icon: "account-card-outline"
                    on_active: sm_cfg.current = "screen_user_account"
                MDNavigationRailItem:
                    icon: "database_cog"
                    on_active: sm_cfg.current = "screen_db"
            ScreenManager:
                id: sm_cfg
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                Screen:
                    name: "screen_my_account"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "my account"
                        halign: "center"
                        font_style: "H3"
                Screen:
                    name: "screen_user_account"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "user account"
                        halign: "center"
                        font_style: "H3"
                Screen:
                    name: "screen_db"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "database"
                        halign: "center"
                        font_style: "H3"
```

As i understand, it should work correctly but its not. It just cycling through all the screen. I wonder why

[image: wrong screen]

My account screen should only shows when the first item of the menu is active.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: better create minimal working code so we could copy and test it

Answer (score 0):

So i solved my problem.

Turns out i need to use `on_press` instead of `on_active`

I missed there is a `on_press` event for this widget. I only saw `on_item_pressed` which returns an error.